# AngularJS binding: what is "<?"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, binding

I have been searching for over 10 minutes now for an answer to this, so I'm sure others will find this useful too.

What is '<?' in AngularJS databinding for a directive?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that:

- '<' is one-way binding
- '?' makes it optional